# Javascript variable scope for objects created within function

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects

Consider this code,

```
var getPerson = function() {
    var _name = "";
    var person = {};

    person.getName = function() {
        return _name;
    }

    person.setName = function(value) {
        _name = value;
    }

    return person;
}


p1 = getPerson();
p1.setName("foo");

p2 = getPerson();
p2.setName("bar");

console.log(p1.getName()); // logs "foo"
console.log(p2.getName()); // logs "bar"
```

Could someone explain the scope of _name here? p1._name and p2._name do not exist. Where is that variable really being stored?

Comment: I think you are probably coming to JavaScript from a Java background.

Comment: Variables are stored in *scopes*, not in objects (like properties are).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_name` is scoped to the `getPerson` function, since it is there that it is declared using the `var` keyword.

Any functions that are nested inside `getPerson` will inherit the variables declared in `getPerson`, and they can override this to declare their own variables. [This concept is called `closure`](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/) and is worth understanding before doing any serious development in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, scope is not determined by block (as in Java), but is [*function* scoped](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/).

So, the `_name` in the `setName` function is the same `_name` that is declared in `getPerson`.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about function-scoping but was confused when p1 & p2 stored different values. Did a little more experimentation and figured that there's a function scope associated with each call to getPerson(). If p1 and p2 are born out of the same call, then they share the same function scope

Answer (score 1):

`_name` is scoped to any code within the `getPerson()` function.

In Javascript, a local variable in a function is scoped to within that particular invocation of the function and each invocation of the function creates a new set of local variables.  Also, those local variables are garbage collected just like other variables.  They are not strictly stored on a stack that is destroyed when the function exits.

Because of the garbage collection, a variable inside a function will survive as long as code that is still reachable has a reference to that variable.  So, in your `getPerson()` function, the scope of the `_name` variable is a particular invocation of the `getPerson()` function, but the lifetime of the variable is as long as some code can still reach that variable, even long after the invocation of `getPerson()` has finished.

This is referred to as a closure in Javascript and is an extremely valuable and useful tool.

Because `person.getName()` and `person.setName()` still have a reference to the `_name` variable even long after the `getPerson()` function has finished execution, it will remain alive and will not be garbage collected by the language.

So, the `scope` is determined by the declaration of the variable.  `_name` is scoped to within the function that is it declared in and any other child scopes that also exist within that function.  Javascript has `lexical` scope (which means the scope is determined by where/how it is declared).  But, the lifetime of a variable within a scope is separately determined by the garbage collector and a variable within a scope can live much beyond the execution of the function that created the scope as long as some other reachable code still has a reference to that variable.

I like to think of a function scope as, itself, a garbage collected entity in Javascript.  While some implementations of Javascript might even be more granular than a whole scope (e.g. garbage collecting individual variables within the scope as possible), the concept of a scope that is garbage collected instead of stack-based gives you a framework for understanding the difference between a language like Javascript and a language like C++ that uses an explicit stack frame to determine the life of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably coming to JavaScript from a Java background.

`var _name = "";` defines the `_name` variable in the scope of the anonymous function (the function assigned to `getPerson`). The variable is not attached to any object, it's just an ordinary variable.

If you really want to do p1._name and p2._name, you can do one or two workarounds.

## Making it a property of the returned object

```
var getPerson = function() {
    var person = {
      _name: ''
    };

    person.getName = function() {
        return this._name;
    }

    person.setName = function(value) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    return person;
}


p1 = getPerson();
p1.setName("foo");

p2 = getPerson();
p2.setName("bar");

console.log(p1.getName()); // logs "foo"
console.log(p2.getName()); // logs "bar"

console.log(p1._name); // logs "foo"
console.log(p2._name); // logs "bar"
```

## Creating a getter on the returned object

```
var getPerson = function() {
    var _name = "";

    var person = {
        get _name () {
            return _name;
        }
    };

    person.getName = function() {
        return _name;
    }

    person.setName = function(value) {
        _name = value;
    }

    return person;
}


p1 = getPerson();
p1.setName("foo");

p2 = getPerson();
p2.setName("bar");

console.log(p1.getName()); // logs "foo"
console.log(p2.getName()); // logs "bar"

console.log(p1._name); // logs "foo"
console.log(p2._name); // logs "bar"
```

There are many other ways you can accomplish this; JavaScript is a dynamic language.

## Bonus tip

What you have above is called a closure. By returning `person`, you expose the methods `person.getName` and `person.setName`. Because these methods are defined inside `getPerson`, they get access to the `_name` variable too (because `_name` is defined inside the same function).

Codes outside `getPerson` can't access `_name`, but they can access if (in a controlled manner) through the getName and setName methods. This creates privacy for the `_name` variable.